# Get full path from shortened path in C#

Tags: c#, filepath

I have a path in the following format: 
`C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\java.exe`

It works as an environment variable, but it doesnt in C#.

Can someone tell me how to get full path to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\java.exe`

Comment: post the code on how you are setting the variable.

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-o0ox1AYkRos/UG0KAkQ0LGI/AAAAAAAAAYc/645-BgacBU8/w357-h155-p-k/Untitled.png Sorry i dont know how post image

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Path.GetFullPath()`.

Note that using short paths as-is should also work.

Comment: ...unless you want your software to pass Windows Logo Testing, in which case your software cannot rely on 8.3 paths.

Comment: @BradleySmith: But passing them to `GetFullPath()` doesn't mean relying on them? That problem must be solved at wherever the strings are coming from.

Comment: My comment was in reference to the second part of your answer (using short paths as-is).

Comment: @BradleySmith but "handling short paths correctly" != "relying on short paths"

Comment: @BradleySmith: I know.  My point is that I don't think `GetFullPath()` would help there; it still relies on them

Comment: Pth.GetFullPath() return same as input. It doesnt work for me